# How to build Ubuntu Touch using manufacturer's kernal source for Android tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting-ubuntu-touch

I have a rooted Android device and its manufacturer's kernal in zip & tar format. Can anyone explain me step by step that how I can build Ubuntu touch ROM for this device using available kernel?

Comment: Read porting guide on the Ubuntu developer portal, talk to people on Ubuntu and Android developer IRC channels or mailing lists. Porting is creative and learning experience. Porting guide (may be out of date or not): https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/porting-new-device/

Comment: I tried to connect with people on Ubuntu touch channel at IRC channel but everytime unsuccessful. I think IRC channels are not working. Can you tell me another way to port Ubuntu Touch to my tablet.